# Check if column contains type string (object)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, dataset

I have a huge dataset with thousands of rows and hundreds of columns. One of these columns contain a string because I am getting an error. I want to locate this string. All my columns are supposed to be float values, however one of these columns has a type `str` somewhere.

How can I loop through a particular column using `Pandas` and print only the row that is of type `str`? I want to find out what the string(s) are so I can convert them to their numerical equivalent.

Comment: You can use `DataFrame.dtypes` as well

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `applymap` with `type`

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'C1': [1,2,3,'4'], 'C2': [10, 20, '3',40]})

df.applymap(type)==str
Out[73]: 
      C1     C2
0  False  False
1  False  False
2  False   True
3   True  False
```

Here you know the str cell. 
Then we using `np.where` to locate it

```
np.where((df.applymap(type)==str))
Out[75]: (array([2, 3], dtype=int64), array([1, 0], dtype=int64))
```

Comment: Can you translate that output for me?

Comment: @Bolboa the 1st array mean the row index , and 2nd mean the column index

Answer (score 2):

If your goal is to convert everything to numerical values, then you can use this approach:

Sample DF:

```
In [126]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(15).reshape(5,3)).add_prefix('col')

In [127]: df.loc[0,'col0'] = 'XXX'

In [128]: df
Out[128]:
  col0  col1  col2
0  XXX     1     2
1    3     4     5
2    6     7     8
3    9    10    11
4   12    13    14

In [129]: df.dtypes
Out[129]:
col0    object
col1     int32
col2     int32
dtype: object
```

Solution:

```
In [130]: df.loc[:, df.dtypes.eq('object')] = df.loc[:, df.dtypes.eq('object')].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')

In [131]: df
Out[131]:
   col0  col1  col2
0   NaN     1     2
1   3.0     4     5
2   6.0     7     8
3   9.0    10    11
4  12.0    13    14

In [132]: df.dtypes
Out[132]:
col0    float64
col1      int32
col2      int32
dtype: object
```